# Show a loading div during ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile app using mostly JQuery Mobile. I have an ajax function using POST and I can't seem to get anything to effect the UI when I fire the click event.  I tried setting

```
$('#cover').show();
```

as the very first thing in the function then I do some basic things like document.getElementById('user') etc to set some variables and check input, but as long as the ajax function is there it won't show the div or even the spinner from JQ Mobile.  Unless I debug and step through the code then the spinner and div show up fine.  I tried setTimeout and putting it in the beforeSend area of the ajax call.  Everything works fine otherwise.  It seemed to work a little better with GET I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

```
$.ajax({                
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: urlString,
    data: jsonstring,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        JSONobj = JSON.parse(data);         
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
          //console.log('BeforeSend');
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        //console.log('Complete');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are specifying `async: false` which turns it into a synchronous call. You should make your "loading" div fully appear before you make the non-ajax call. Oh, and the page might appear to freeze during the call, mostly because it is frozen.

Comment: And don't use document.getElementById when you have $("#id")

Comment: I thought about the async: true before, I'll try that again.  I think I'll have to load all the objects properties there then instead of in a separate function.

Comment: I just made it async: true and moved all JSON object fillers to the success area, it seems to work.  Thanks!

Comment: TheZ 's answer is correct, I'm not sure how to set it as the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ajax Global handlers to handle this:

```
$(document). 
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $('#cover').show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        $('#cover').hide();
    });
```

This way you don't have to worry about showing/hiding the overlay on individual Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#someButton").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault() //if you want to prevent default action

    $('#cover').fadeIn(100,function(){

       $.ajax({     
              url: "someurl",
              data: "Somedata",
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",        
              },
              success: function (data) {
                   JSONobj = JSON.parse(data);
                   $('#cover').fadeOut(100);        
              },
               complete: function (xhr) {
                   $('#cover').fadeOut(100);
              }
       });  

    }); 

});
```